# Removing emacs prelude package

Tags: emacs, uninstallation, emacs-prelude

I installed prelude with curl before realizing that the OSX version of emacs is too old for prelude. Now I can't find any documentation on how to remove it and I'm hesitant to just start deleting files in my emacs folder that have the word 'prelude' in them. Is there a command to remove this?

Comment: How about downloading a separate prelude package to a working folder and see what files/folders it contains?  Then, there is no guessing involved regarding what your curl command installed.  Most packages and starter kits do not come with an "uninstall" utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to ask prelude where it is installed. Try this (even if emacs does not fully load all prelude):

ESC-x describe-variable  prelude-dir

It will tell you where prelude is being loaded from.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and solved this problem this morning. Here what I do:

1. cd home/yourusrname
2. find .emacs and .emacs.d, if not. press Cril + h.
3. You will also see 2 files named like .emacs-pre-prelude.. and .emacs- pre-prelude.tgz .These are your .emacs and .emacs.d before you install prelude.
4. del .emacs and .emacs.d
5. rename .emacs-pre-prelude as .emacs
6. tar  .emacs.d-pre-prelude.tgz find the .emacs.d in it and mv it to your /home/yourusrname/. restart emacs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.